# What is the revocation operation in computers and what data to store?

Tags: data-structures, operating-system

The revocation operation of computer is "Ctrl+Z". Is there a stack before operation? When I think about writing code, I am very curious about it. Do I still use other structures to store previous records? Thank you！

Comment: Are you asking how to implement an undo operation?

Comment: @JimMischel Yes